# Antivírus reconhece o TIdHTTP como uma ameaça no Delphi, o que fazer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6, antivirus

Estou usando o Delphi RAD XE6, porém meu Avast está acusando toda aplicação portadora do componente TIdHTTP como um vírus, ainda que a aplicação tenha apenas um formulário vazio, tentei até criar o componente em tempo de execução em forma de variável, porém o problema persistiu, o que eu faço?

Comment: Acho difícil ser um problema generalizado, pois se fosse este o caso existiriam muitas pessoas na internet reclamando... Já tentou atualizar seu Avast? Fiz testes aqui agora com o Delphi 7 e o XE3, usando IdHTTP do Indy 10, e não houve nenhum conflito com o meu Avast (última versão).

Comment: Não sei o que houve, mas eu resolvi o problema entrando em contato com a empresa do Avast, eles me responderam por e-mail e resolveram o problema num prazo de 10 horas mandando atualizações de definição de vírus para todo o mundo. Tudo o que eu tive quefazer foi descrever o problema e enviar o arquivo para este site: https://support.avast.com